# Select text from Menu Token field in Xcode UITests

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing

[image: UITests - token field with dropdown menu]

I saw a WWDC video about `UITests` that said if you double-click the blue token field in Xcode, it will become text and remove the menu (aka. the blue thing), but when I double-click the field, it just gets removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The double-tap trick is, indeed, not working in Xcode 9. However, we can always use the power of Regex.

For this to work, either:

- open the Find navigator on the left sidebar (the fourth icon from the left) and choose Replace from the first toggle on the top
- navigate to **Find/Find and Replace...**

After that, choose the **Regular Expression** option by:

- clicking on the menu and changing the searching method if you're using the Find navigator
- or by opening the menu on the right side (to the right of the button with the text **Aa**) if you prefer to use the local Find and Replace dialog

The start of the token field is always indicated with `/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/`, followed by the actual selected text. After that, there is a textual representation of all the possible options, finished with `@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/`. Example:

`/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.cells.buttons["Button Text"]/*[[".cells.buttons[\"Button Text\"]",".buttons[\"Button Text\"]"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[1]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/`

In our Regex, we should delete everything **but** the text that comes directly after `/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/` and before the options block. We can achieve this by capturing that snippet and replacing all of this mess with just that snippet.

For **Replace**, enter the following:

```
/\*@START_MENU_TOKEN@\*/(.*.)/\*(.*.)@END_MENU_TOKEN@\*/
```

...and for **With**, enter this:

```
$1
```

Click on **Replace** if you only want to delete the token field from the nearest occurrence after your cursor or choose **All** if you want to remove them all.

[image: screenshot of the Find and Replace... dialog]

Comment: Thank you! This does work and will still save a lot of time!

Comment: Apparently this is fixed in Xcode 10 (juste tested with beta 6)